# Why would Delphi code to update a TMYQuery blob field work then crash?

Tags: delphi, blob

I am writing a record to encapsulate the functionality of reading and writing blob fields, from or to files. It all basically works: I can assign blobs in new records, and save files from existing blob fields.

This function to update a blob from a new file works, but crashes.

```
procedure TBlobFunction.UpdateRecord(id: int64; const filename: string);
var qry: TDataset;
    blob: TStream;
    fs: TFileStream;
begin
  HourGlass(true);
  qry := DM.CreateQry('SELECT ' + join([blobfield, idfield, filenamefield], ', ')
            +#10' FROM ' + tablename
            +#10'WHERE ' + idfield + ' = ' + id.ToString);
  blob := nil;
  fs := nil;
  try
    qry.Edit;
    qry.FieldByName(filenamefield).AsString := fileName;
    blob := qry.CreateBlobStream(qry.FieldByName(blobfield), bmWrite);
    blob.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    fs := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    blob.CopyFrom(fs, fs.Size);
    qry.Post;
  finally
    qry.Free;
    fs.Free;
    blob.Free;
  end;
  HourGlass(false);
end{ UpdateRecord};
```

This very similar code, to create a new record, works without crashing:

```
function TBlobFunction.NewRecord(const filename: TFilename): int64;
var qry: TDataset;
    blob: TStream;
    fs: TFileStream;
begin
  fs := nil;
  blob := nil;
  qry := DM.CreateQry('SELECT ' + join([blobfield, idfield, filenamefield], ', ') +' FROM ' + tablename + ' LIMIT 0');
  try
    qry.Insert;
    qry.FieldByName(filenamefield).AsString := FileName;
    blob := qry.CreateBlobStream(qry.FieldByName(blobfield), bmWrite);
    blob.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    fs := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    blob.CopyFrom(fs, fs.Size);
    qry.Post;
    result := qry.FieldByName(idfield).AsLargeInt;
  finally
    fs.Free;
    blob.Free;
    qry.Free;
  end;
end{ NewRecord};
```

Can anyone see a problem?

TIA
Mark

Comment: what does "works, but crashes" mean? (what works, how does it crash?)

Comment: ... and on what line does it crash/what is on the IDE call stack (`View | Debug Windows | Call stack`) when it does.

Comment: In the code that crashes, you are freeing the Query object before freeing the Blob stream. In the code that works, you are freeing the Blob stream  before freeing the Query object.

Comment: The record is updated when I rerun the app. I can save the blob to a file and it is the file I update it to. The crash occurs when I free the blob. Which helped me to solve me own problem!  The blob stream object must be owned by the query.

Comment: Ah, the incomparable Remy Lebeau caught it as I was posting. Yes. So, I guess I do not have to free the blob object at all?

Comment: @MarkPatterson yes, you do have to free it. But it shares resources with the query, so you have to free them in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, TStream is not a TComponent, I guess a good general rule to follow to avoid this sort of thing is last-in first out, i.e. free objects in the reverse order of their creation, as you would if each object had its own try finally block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, provided by Remy Lebeau, is to free the blob before the query it comes from is freed. I could put each object that needed freeing in its own try .. finally block, but I prefer to keep the code less cluttered.

```
procedure TBlobFunction.UpdateRecord(id: int64; const filename: string);
var qry: TDataset;
    blob: TStream;
    fs: TFileStream;
begin
  HourGlass(true);
  qry := DM.CreateQry('SELECT ' + join([blobfield, idfield, filenamefield], ', ')
            +#10' FROM ' + tablename
            +#10'WHERE ' + idfield + ' = ' + id.ToString);
  blob := nil;
  fs := nil;
  try
    qry.Edit;
    qry.FieldByName(filenamefield).AsString := fileName;
    blob := qry.CreateBlobStream(qry.FieldByName(blobfield), bmWrite);
    blob.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    fs := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    blob.CopyFrom(fs, fs.Size);
    qry.Post;
  finally
    fs.Free;
    blob.Free;
    qry.Free;
  end;
  HourGlass(false);
end{ UpdateRecord};
```

Of course not crashing has its advantages as well, but this is fine.